# Как с помощью JS создать менеджер задач?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется простая форма для создания новых задач, хотелось бы понять, как с помощью `JS` добавлять и удалять задачи динамически.

В форме имеются два поля и кнопка: **название**, **описание**.

Необходимо ввести данные в поля и добавить задачу по нажатию на кнопку в левый блок. По нажатию на крестик нужно удалять блок с задачей полностью.

**Примечания**: я новичок в `JS`, хотелось бы видеть подробные объяснения тех или иных действий, верстка не столь важна, мне главное понять принцип и основы в `JS`. Сохранять задачи в `localStorage` **не обязательно**!

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1000px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.fixed-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#column-left {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 470px;
  float: left;
  height: 515px;
}

#Spisok-del {
  /**display: none;*/
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 30px 0px 35px 0px;
}

.Spiski-container {
  /**display: none;*/
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 470px;
  float: left;
  height: 135px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#column-right {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 470px;
  float: right;
  height: 525px;
}

#Spisok {
  margin-top: 65px;
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 470px;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
}

#Delo {
  margin-top: 65px;
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 470px;
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
}

.zagolovok {
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pole-nazvanie {
  width: 390px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.delo-settins {
  margin: 30px 0px 35px 40px;
}

.pole-opisanie {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 390px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.button-delo {
  background: #2174fd;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 225px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Список дел</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fixed-container">
    <div id="Spiski">
      <h2 id="Spisok">Список дел</h2>
      <h2 id="Delo">Добавить новое дело</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="column-left">
      <div class="Spiski-container" id="Spiski">
        <h2 id="Spisok-del">Список пуст...</h2>
        <ul class="list">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column-right">
      <div class="delo-settins">
        <div class="zagolovok">*Название</div>
        <input class="pole-nazvanie" type="nazvanie-form" name="Название">
        <div class="zagolovok">*Описание</div>
        <input class="pole-opisanie" type="opisanie-form" name="Название">

        <button class="button-delo" disabled="disabled">Добавить дело</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: вопрос задайте...с чем помочь то ?

Comment: Я не знаю как тут приятно общаться. Буду благодарна если кто-то поможет. Не обязательно писать решение. Просто помочь понять как написать javascript тоже будет хорошо, может какую статью посоветуете или урок именно по созданию списков дел или чего-то похожего. Я только недавно начала учить html, поэтому прошу не ругать за тупость. Очень хочу разобраться!

Comment: Вопрос состоит в коде  javascript. Я не могу его написать! Совсем(

Comment: Опишите что не получается, какая задача перед вами...

Comment: Виталий, моя задача сделать  javascript так, чтобы при написании слов в полях:
Название и Описание. Создавались списки дел слева. При этом по клику на крестик она удалялись.

Comment: @ВикаПравдюк у вас два раза код css повторяется. Вы пропустили html, но, когда вы его добавите, все равно будет не понятно, что с javascript

Comment: Чтобы свестать такое, нужно знать html,css,js (в качестве шаблона стилей использовал бы `bootstrap`) . С `js` быстро разобраться не получиться...надо вникать. Но его нужно не много. И после нажатия кнопки "Добавить дело", если Вам нужно его сохранить куда-то, то нужен сервер (php,c#,python, etc...) И по хорошему база данных

Comment: Где вы планируете хранить записи и планируете ли вы хранить их вообще? Если не хранить данные даже в том же localStorage , то при перезагрузке страницы она просто сотрет все записи.

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, смотрите для такого списка я так поняла не нужен сервер: https://codepen.io/akoptsov/pen/vGxyaa (это как пример но проще)
У меня будет похожий, может чуть сложнее. js вникаю, но те уроки что смотрю мне мало, объясняют урезано, а объяснения тет а тет нет. Со стилями пофиг, мне нужна помощь именно js. Может посоветуете ресурс где почитать или изучить.
А сервер не поняла зачем? Мне не нужно условно "сохранение", нужно только чтобы сами списки появлялись и удалялись. Как на картинке.

Comment: @MoloF, хранить не планирую.

Comment: Ну тогда вам нужно знать: 1) Уметь производить поиск по селекторам и знать их 2) Уметь оперировать DOM-эл-тами с помощью js

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, совет побольше изучить селекторы и DOM-эл-ты?

Comment: Странно кстати, почему стили не показываются, при нажатии выполнить код) Со стилями то у меня все ок

Comment: Попробуйпосмотреть блог этого блоггера, он хорошо обьясняет, но на английском
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClb90NQQcskPUGDIXsQEz5Q

Comment: @ВикаПравдюк да,и это тоже. Но я имел в виду уметь манипулировать DOM-эл-ами с помощью js.

Comment: Ну как всегда, только написал свой ответ и занялся подробным объяснением как вопрос просто взяли и закрыли. Все желание отпадает прям отвечать подробно. https://imgur.com/nHcmx9n

Comment: @MoloF Строго говоря, закрыли по делу, вопрос отвратительно оформлен

Comment: @YuriPokhylko , можно было просто исправить вопрос, а не закрывать, ведь ответ дан исчерпывающий. Тем более автор вопроса новичок и не знает толком про SO и его правила, я тоже плохо составлял первое время вопросы, здесь ничего такого в этом нет.

Comment: @MoloF закрытие вопроса - это ведь не конец. После внесения в него правок, он попадёт в очередь на проверку. А там уже участники решат, нужно переоткрывать или нет ^_^

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik вы можете открыть вопрос? Я внес необходимые правки!

Comment: @MoloF вижу. Просто обычно модераторы стараются единолично такие вещи не делать, а оставлять решение за сообществом. Я за вопросом сегодня послежу ещё. Если в очереди хотя бы несколько человек проголосуют за открытие, то я открою.

Comment: @MoloF в таких случаях ещё можно людей в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) попросить проголосовать за переоткрытие. Там часть проверяльщиков сидит)

Comment: Спасибо тем кто переоткрыл вопрос.
Я задала его не правильно. Думала весь текст надо уместить в заголовке. Большое спасибо тем кто исправил и сделал понятнее описание задачи. И спасибо всем кто ответил, это все равно помощь новичку!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взял готовую разметку у **Виталия Шебаниц**.

Я захотел оставить более подробный ответ без использования сторонних библиотек для `JS`.

---

Используемые методы:

- document.[querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- document.[addEventListener(event, callback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- document.[createElement(tagName)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)
- element.[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).[add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- element.[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- element.[appendChild(element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

---

Объясняю последовательность действий:

1. Я обозначил все необходимые элементы в начале кода, взял их с помощью `querySelector()`
2. Повесил событие `click` на кнопку c помощью метода `addEventListener()`
3. Создал `callback` функцию, в которой сделал проверку на поля: название и описание
4. Создал пустой DIV элемент с помощью `createElement()`
5. Установил для пустого элемента два класса: `card`, `mt-2`
6. Вставил в элемент строку состоящую из HTML кода с помощью appendChild()
7. Обнулил значение полей: название, описание
8. Добавил слушатель на контейнер с задачами
9. Проверяю не был нажат крестик внутри контейнера с помощью `event.target.closest('.close')`
10. Если нажат крестик, возвращаюсь до самого элемента с классом `.card` и удаляю его с помощью метода `remove()`

```js
// Контейнер в который мы будем помещать задачи.
const container = document.querySelector('#taskList');

// Поле - ввод, название задачи
const name = document.querySelector('#taskTitle');

// Поле - ввод, описание задачи
const description = document.querySelector('#taskDescription');

// Кнопка
const button = document.querySelector('#taskAddButton');

// Добавляем слушатель на кнопку, в качестве первого аргумента передаем событие, нам необходимо нажатие - click. В качестве второго аргумента мы передаем функцию (callback), по нажатию на кнопку мы будем возвращены в эту функцию.
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

 // Проверяем заполенны ли поля название и описание, если не заполнено хотя-бы одно поле - прерываем дальнейшее выполнение функции возвратив пустое значение.
 if (!name.value || !description.value) return;

 // Создаем элемент DIV
 const task = document.createElement('div');

 // Добавляем элементу DIV два класса: card и mt-2
 task.classList.add('card', 'mt-2');

 // Вставляем HTML код прямо в созданный элемент
 task.innerHTML = `
  <div class="card-header d-flex">
   <div class="card-title">
    <span>${name.value}</span>
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="close d-flex ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
   <span>${description.value}</span>
  </div>
 `;

   // Добавляем в контейнер созданный элемент
   container.appendChild(task);

 // Обнуляем значения полей названия и описания
 name.value = '';
 description.value = '';
});


// Так как мы динамически добавляем элементы на страницу, нам необходимо за пределами самого элемента прослушать не было ли нажато крестика, который будет удалять задачу
container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   // Проверяем на какой элемент мы кликнули, если мы кликнули на элемент который содержит в себе класс .close то удаляем весь родительский блок
 if (e.target.closest('.close'))
  // Поднимаемся до родительского контейнера и удаляем его полностью
  e.target.closest('.card').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" id="taskList">
 
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="addForm">
      <form onsubmit="return false;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="taskTitle">Название</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskTitle" aria-describedby="taskTitleHelp">
          <small id="taskTitleHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Введите название задания.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="taskDescription">Описание</label>
          <textarea rows="5" cols="45" id="taskDescription" name="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="taskAddButton">Добавить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я использовал `bootstrap 4` и `jQuery`

```js
$("#taskAddButton").click(function() {// нахожу кнопку и добавляю к нему эвент на клик
  $("#taskList").append(`<div class="card mt-2"><div class="card-header d-flex"><div class="card-title"><span>${$("#taskTitle").val()}</span></div><button type="button" class="close d-flex ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="card-body"><span>${$("#taskDescription").val()}</span></div></div>`);
  //append = вставляет в элемент, над которым он вызван другой эл-нт (скобках)
  //$("#..") - поиск элемента по id
  //$("#..").val - получения значения для input
});

$("#taskList").on("click", ".close", function() {// нахожу крестик и навешиваю на него событие по клику. Такой способ потому что он динамический.
  $(this).closest(".card").remove(); // remove - удаляет выбранный эл-нт
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" id="taskList">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="addForm">
      <form onsubmit="return false;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="taskTitle">Название</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskTitle" aria-describedby="taskTitleHelp">
          <small id="taskTitleHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Введите название задания.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="taskDescription">Описание</label>
          <textarea rows="5" cols="45" id="taskDescription" name="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="taskAddButton">Добавить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо кто посоветовал что-то. Особенно Виталий спасибо, можно отталкиваться от вашего примера!
Пошла учится дальше.

Comment: @ВикаПравдюк Пожалуйста, и удачи в учебе :)