# Помощь с написанием кода JS Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Я новичек, не сильно разбираюсь в верстке. Но если сверстать - это пол беды, то написать код на JS меня поставило в тупик, помогите пожалуйста написать код на JS и по возможности объяснить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Нужно сделать автоматизированное появление дел слева после нажатия на кнопку "Добавить дело".

Comment: Забыл добавить ссылку на код 
[ссылка](https://codepen.io/zakenchannel/pen/pojmyge)

Comment: а Дизайн "дела" с потолка брать?

Comment: В каком смысле? Я показал, что нужно примерно как на картинке, код всей страницы отправил в коментарии. Что еще нужно?

Comment: Я уже оставлял ответ на вопрос: [Как с помощью JS создать менеджер задач?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109452)

Comment: не всегда найдется тот человек, который будет объяснять вам как решать задачи, приучите себя это делать самостоятельна, да, "увы", профессия такая, но в этом и кайф, сначала разберитесь в самой задаче, поймите что она должна делать и мелкими шагами идите, ну, к примеру, нужно ПРИ КЛИКЕ (пошли сразу гуглить как делать клик на Js/Jq) нужно ДОБАВЛЯТЬ (пошли гуглить как создать новый элемент) что-то и тому подобное, двигайтесь маленькими шагами, пока не стоит мыслить глобально, а когда возникнет вопрос, по типу: делают все так, но не получается - пишите сюда (но сначала поищите!)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за прмрщь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let  stick = document.createElement('div');
  let spisok = document.getElementById('spisok');
  let spisokn = document.getElementById('spisok-none');
  stick.innerHTML = `<div class="title-bar"><span>X</span>${e.target.elements.title.value}</div>${e.target.elements.text.value}</div>`;
  stick.querySelector('span').onclick = function (e) {
    try {
      spisok.removeChild(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
      if (spisok.innerHTML == '') {
          spisokn.style.display = 'block';
      }
    } catch (e){}
  }
  spisokn.style.display = 'none';
  spisok.appendChild(stick);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 1000px;
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
body{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.fixed-container{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
#left-column{
 width: 470px;
 min-height: 600px;
 float: left;
}
#spisok-none{
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#spisok{
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#spisok > div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
    position:relative;
  width: 460px;
  padding: 10px;
    margin:5px 0;
    color:#555;
}
#spisok > div .title-bar span {
  position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#spisok > div .title-bar {
    border-bottom:1px solid #c8c8c8;
    line-height:25px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#right-column{
 float: right;
 width: 510px;
 min-height: 600px;
 float: right;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
 #mini-ban{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 470px;
  height: 540px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
 }
 #name{
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
 }
 #text-bar{
  height: 45px;
  width: 390px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #ebebeb;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 30px;
 }
 #big-text-bar{
  height: 230px;
  width: 390px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #ebebeb;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  resize: none;
 }
 #enter-button{
  width: 224px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #2174fd;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
 }
 #about{
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="fixed-container">
 <div id="banners">
  <div id="left-column">
  <h2 id="your-spisok">Список дел:</h2>
    <div id="spisok-none">Список пуст...</div>
  <div id="spisok"></div>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="fixed-container">
 <div id="right-column">
  <h2>Добавить новое дело</h2>
 <div id="mini-ban">
  <form id="myform">
   <div id="name">* Название</div>
   <input id="text-bar" type="text" name="title" required="required">
   <div id="about">* Описание</div>
   <textarea id="big-text-bar" name="text" required="required"></textarea>
      <button id="enter-button">Добавить дело</button>
  </form>
```